# To create a custom connector on Microsoft power automate with reference to custom connect on Docusign

Tags: sharepoint, automated-tests, docusignapi, power-automate, docusignconnect

DocuSign integration with SharePoint using power automate

**Requirement:**
Hi community,
1)I have a template in DocuSign which the user will use to issue a contract/envelope.
2)The contract will be signed by an external recipient and upload additional document via document attachment.
3)Once the recipient upload and sign the contract document, I would like the attachment file to be stored in SharePoint list.

**Steps taken so far:**

1)Created a connect integration in DocuSign with power automate. 2)Tested the connect with web hook.

**Assistance required:**

How do I extract the attachment in the flow from Json file to store the values on SharePoint list.

Till now , I was also referring to the DocuSign link which is explaining the similar scenario but I am facing problem with the integration key.

https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/expanding-power-automate-series-create-custom-docusign-connect-flow

https://www.docusign.com.au/blog/get-the-flow-sending-docusign-envelopes-microsoft-power-automate

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement to send a template using docusign, and then trigger some actions after an envelope is completed, you can use the standard docusign connector for power automate. We have recently recently some great new steps to allow alot more, without needing code.
See the [Power Automate for DocuSign Guide](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301&bundleId=gqy1619537336307&topicId=qno1619537607438.html&_LANG=enus), in particular:

- [Create Envelope from Template](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301&bundleId=gqy1619537336307&topicId=xgv1666552804029.html&_LANG=enus)
- [Triggers](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301&bundleId=gqy1619537336307&topicId=bgr1619538245217.html&_LANG=enus)

Here is a [blog with step by step instructions](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/expanding-power-automate-series-send-envelope) for sending a document from sharepoint. This is similar to what you need, and your requirement will be even easier, since you don't need to get a document from sharepoint, you're just using a template.

If you feel you still need to use a custom connector, let me know and we can troubleshoot it, but best bet is just to use the standard connector, much easier.

Hope that helps